# How to make == value as a list in python

Tags: python

i doin work for scraping data that equal to date.. i need scape data that equal to date in a list....

i try this code but didt works.. but if i use with only single data `listdate = 'Jun 30, 2022'` works...

```
listdate = ['Jun 23, 2022', 'Jun 24, 2022', 'Jun 25, 2022']

lp = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > time')
lpval = lp.get_attribute('title') ==  (listdate)
print(lpval)

if lpval == True :
        print('Do sometin')
else:
        print('Stop')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but incase you want to check against all values in list, you can do `lp.get_attribute('title') in  listdate`, which will return `True` if any of the values in the list match `lp.get_attribute('title')`

Comment: wow thank... solved. `lp.get_attribute('title') in listdate ==  listdate`